# How to make "profile id" in PHP [different]

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdo

Hello guys I am trying to make profile system in PHP. Let's show my codes:

index.php:

```
<?php
include "header.php";
$page = @$_GET["p"];
switch ($page){

    default:
    include "main.php";
    break;

    case "followings":
    include "followings.php";
    break;

    case "profile":
    include "profile.php";
    break; } ?>
```

Until here is working fine for example: when I type: `mypage.com/index.php?p=profile` he is switching to profile.php.. but when I am trying to `mypage/index.php?p=profile?uid=1`, is switching to index.php... 
 I know, because the parameter $_GET["p"] need to be same with the case.
I tried something like this:  `$_GET['p']."#".$_GET['?'];` or if you have a better idea please share guys thank you for your time.

Comment: It is `index.php?p=profile&uid=1`

Comment: To explain what u_mulder changed: he added ampersands (&) to the url to allow multiple get variables in the url.

Comment: OMg you are crazyy :D it works

Comment: very interesting thank you dude

Comment: in profile.php the code for get id should be $getuserid = $_GET["uid"]; ?

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct so far, you have to check your request as mypage/index.php?p=profile?uid=1 this must be mypage/index.php?p=profile&uid=1

Answer (score 0):

in given URL try this:
mypage/index.php?p=profile&uid=1
(there is an Ampersand, not a questionmark in the querystring)

I hope it helps.
Regards,
A.

Comment: Thank you for answer dude :) how i can get this id in URL .. i tryed $getprofileid = $_GET[uid]; echo $getprofileid;

Comment: sorry yea this is working, just the text was on back side on header :D